# Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference. ViewBag.Title is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, viewbag

I want to provide a simple general functionality to show a message at the top of a page whenever I need to inform a user that operation is successful.
My solution would be to put an object into `ViewBag.Info` that contains details about a message, including `bool public IsMessage;`and read it in `_Layout.cshtml` where I have an extra hidden `div`.

The way I am trying to do it in `_Layout.cshtml` is I put what's in `@(ViewBag.Info.IsMessage` (false/true) into a hidden field and read it by JavaScript. If the field contains "true", javascript will invoke a function `ShowEvent()`.

For some reason, if I add the line `@(ViewBag.Info.IsMessage.ToString().ToLower())` VS2010 complains about `ViewBag.Title` in `_Layout.cshtml`.

> "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference"

The code of `_Layout.cshtml` is simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/StyleSheet.css")" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="hidden" id="is-event" name="is-event" value="@(ViewBag.Info.IsMessage.ToString().ToLower())"/>
    <div class="recent-events"></div>
    <div>
        @if (IsSectionDefined("loginfo"))
        {
            @RenderSection("loginfo", false)
        }
        @RenderBody()
        @if (IsSectionDefined("Home"))
        {
            @RenderSection("Home", false)
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the code of the View `Index.cshtml` is:

```
@model TestProject.ViewModels.Account.UserData
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    string identityName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    string userrole = Model.UserRoles.FirstOrDefault();
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<br />
```

As you can see `ViewBag.Title` is defined.

EDIT.
The code of the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // ...
    InfoModel infoModel = new InfoModel()
    {
        IsMessage = true, Duration = 3000, Message = "Logging in successfull", BackgroundColor = "#bbffbb"
    };
    ViewBag.Info = infoModel;
    ViewBag.Title = string.Empty;
    return View(userdata);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get this issue if you attempt to reference a Model from a View which isn't strongly typed. For instance, typing

```
@Model.ID
```

somewhere in the page will attempt to bind to the ID property of the ViewModel - if you haven't defined the model type at the top of the View page with

```
@model MyModel
```

then it will bomb out with this obscure error message.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have defined the `ViewBag.Title` in your controller action. Right now you have defined it in your `Index.cshtml` view but the Layout is rendered first so by that time the value is not yet set.

Comment: VS2010 complaines about `@ViewBag.Title` not `@ViewBag.Info...` and the `Info` object is defined in a controller.

Comment: You are correct. I haven't noticed that you defined ViewBag.Title in the view, not in the controller action. I have updated my answer.

Comment: No. It's still complaining, even though I have added `ViewBag.Title = string.Empty;` in the controller.

Comment: That's very strange. I am unable to reproduce the problem. If ViewBag.Title is set in the controller action you should be able to use it in the Layout.

Comment: Somehow, it starts having problem once I add the line with extra ViewBag but ViewBag properties are fully defined in a controller.

Comment: I did also try this in a new project and the error is still the same :/  Quite frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this happen and it was a misleading error. I have this in my view:

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Generator Tests";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
```

Then lower in the view I had put in a new `@ViewBag.EndDate` but I had not set it and had not checked it for null. The view threw the error on the `@ViewBag.Title` line despite the fact that I could hover over Title and see that it was set. I added the null check for ViewBag.EndDate and now the view works.